# Move UserControl to another parent in Page Stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `page of control`s that I want to be able to `move specific controls by ID to a different parent control server side`.

A simple example being another control loads 2 controls vertically ontop of each other. I want a module that can reference those two modules by ID and lay them out horizontally.

I assume this would have to done after the `Page_Load()` event so that all the controls are loaded.

I think I can accomplish this with a recursive `control.FindControl()` but I'm thinking there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Probably you can not do what I think you try to do, to move the fully render of the control somewhere different. The structure on code behind is not the same as the Dom rendered them. So if you like to move the full render, you need to thing a different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to dynamically move controls around the page then it’s better to programmatically set them on page where it’s needed.

You should be adding controls in the OnInit method that is run before the page load.

Roughly, the OnInit method would look like

a) check the state of the page and decide where to add control

b) add control where needed

Comment: This is for the DotNetNuke system. Think of it as a module. I want to utilize a module to move another module (user control) to another specific user control.